# Why is this function invoked?

Tags: javascript, function

Why does this code work? - http://jsfiddle.net/Mq9Ap/1/

```
$(function() {

    function outer() {
        var counter = 0;
        function inner() {
            alert(counter);
            counter++;
        }
        return inner;
    }

    var x = outer(); // As we're calling outer here, x is a reference to inner 
    x(); // alerts 0
    x(); // alerts 1

});
```

But it only runs once if i change `return inner` to `return inner()`

Edit:

I've confused the intent of my question by mentioning parenthesis. I'm still confused how the inner function is called at all as x() only points to the outer function.

Does the compiler know it should invoke a function if the return value is a pointer to a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've cracked it; my confusion was not so much `return inner;` but it was:

```
var x = outer();
```

I now understand that x holds the **return value of outer because of the () invocation** which is a function reference to `b`, so if we now add another () around this returned value, it then invokes that referenced inner function, similar to outer()();

```
function outer() {
    var counter = 0;
    function inner() {
        console.log(counter);
        counter++;
    }
    return inner;
}

outer()();
outer()();
outer()();

//output
0
0
0

var x = outer(); 
x();
x();
x();

//output
0
1
2
```

The last section `var x` works because the outer has been invoked with `outer()`. When the inner is then called with `x();` each time, the counter is already on the stack so the inner function sees it as a static var...i presume.

Confusing stuff this javascript :(

Edit:

Another eureka moment - I realised that `outer()();` doesn't work because each time the first `outer()` is called, it creates a new function context and `var counter` is initialised each time on the stack and when the second invocation is called, the counter will always be set to zero.

The `x = outer();` keeps the counter value from previous function calls, because the function context is saved in `x` and `var counter` is only initialised once so it's never reset.

Answer (score 2):

`return inner` returns the inner function. This can then be called.

`return inner()` immediately runs the inner function (alerting `0`), then returns its return value (undefined). You then get an error that `undefined` is not a function (when `x()` tries to call it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer; may i kindly ask if you can sense check my logic as i tried to answer my own question https://stackoverflow.com/a/23122932/1837472. I value your feedback, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `return inner();`, you are actually invoking `inner` and returning the return value , which in this case is `undefined` since nothing is actually returned. This will then result in an error because `undefined` is not a function (when you try to call it by doing `x()`).

When you do `return inner;`, you are actually returning a reference to the inner function.

Answer (score 0):

It is the fact of what you return.

`return inner();` actually call the inner function and get the result. That result will be returned. Since `inner` function does not return anything explicitly, by default it returns `undefined`. Now `x` is undefined. You cannot make call on undefined `x`.

`return inner;` actually returns reference to inner function. So now `x` is reference to a function. You can execute `x()` which will actually invoke `inner` closure function.

Comment: I was still confused until the last bit of your comment; are you saying that the compiler knows it should automatically invoke a variable if it's a pointer to another function when it hits a return statement?

Comment: Updated my answer. It will not invoke when you return a function reference.